# string.replace databound column in Gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, boundfield

Im currently pulling a string comment from a DB into a gridview to display to the user.  Throughout the string i have placed `<br/>`s where i want linebreaks, but am wondering how to replace the `<br/>`s with "Environment.Newline"s. the column is simply a boundfield.

```
  <Columns>  
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Comment" DataField="UAComment" />
  </Columns>
```

and im populating the table with an adapter and Fill():

```
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            recordsFound = adapter.Fill(table);
            results.Text = recordsFound + " records matching query";
            connection.Close();
```

Thanks for any info.

ps: also tried already building the string/submitting the string to the database with newlines but cant seem to get it to pull out of the db with the proper formatting.

```
public void Group(String message)
    {
        log.Append(": Group :");
        log.AppendFormat(message);
        log.Append("<br/>");
    }


    public String GetLog()
    {
        log.Replace("<br/>", Environment.NewLine);
        return log.ToString();
    }
```

also substituted "Environment.Newline" with @"\n", "\n", @"\r", "\r"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be use a template field instead of bound field and add bind a literal in the template field with current column value. Using this it will render all the stuff in html format and the line breaks come autometically.

**Example :**

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        Comment
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Literal1" Text='<%# Eval("UAComment") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Hope this will fix you problem

Comment: beautiful answer thankyou Kundan, just reformatted the literal a bit `<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Literal1" Text='<%# Eval("UAComment")%>' />`

Comment: Thanks @LinksTune, This was an typo mistake i have corrected it.