# How to store multiline text in SQL Server 2008 keeping track of new line in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, newline, multilinestring

I am developing an intranet ASP.NET web site. I am saving user comments from an asp.net multiline textbox into a SQL Server database, and display exactly as it is written by user in Gridview.

Suppose a user enter following string:

```
1.Task1
2.Task2
3.Task3
```

then the retreived data in the gridview should be same as user entered it before saving.

While debugging, I tried replacing `\r\n` with `<br/>` but gridview is displaying `<br/>` as it is..not tasking a new line.

I am using c#.

I have found the solution for it Using Literal Control.

Now, there is one new Problem where i am not using Gridview.I am generating Comments as html and sending it as a mail body,
Suppose a user enter following string:

```
1.Task1
   a.T1
   b.T2
   c.T3
2.Modules
  a.Module A
  b.Module B
  c.Module C
```

Line Break `<br  />` when Replaced with `/n` is taking the content only to new line not taking spaces for Second Line Automatically.and the mail body html is generating it like this:

```
 1.Task1  
 a.T1  
 b.T2  
 c.T3  
 2.Modules  
 a.Module A  
 b.Module B  
 c.Module C
```

Which is not what i Expect.

Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: are you showing the comments in label control in the grid view?

Comment: Hi thanks for Noticing my prob.No,i am using BoundField .Doing a direct Binding.I am not using Templatefield.i want to show the data in Boundfield. Thanks

Comment: post your gridview code please.

Comment: I think you will get your answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091832/string-replace-databound-column-in-gridview

Comment: Hi Dey ,i saw the Post,i got my Answer.Thanks a lot .

Comment: I'm happy that you got your answer. :) Don't forget to upvote the question and answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use carriage returns when you save the text and when displaying it in the grid, you can replace it as

```
'<%# Eval("TheName").ToString().Replace("\n", "<br />") %>'
```

Comment: Hi Srinivas.i am trying your method.Thanks for Reply.

Comment: @nks : Ok. Please reply after trying.